# Routes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to fix one question about routing in Rails. There is 'User' model with roles : user.restaurant_owner? and user.shop_owner?. Users are admins only. Also there is a super user (it's me). I want that  when user inputs `'http://somesite.com/his_name'` his request is processed the controller 'restaurants' or 'shops' according to his role and name. For example, he inputs 'http://somesite.com/stanly' and he gets view from 'http://somesite.com/restaurants/5', because 'stanly' is owner of restaurant with '5' id; if he inputs 'http://somesite.com/marylin' and he gets view from 'http://somesite.com/shops/101', because 'marylin' is owner of shop with '101' id. 
I want to do it, because I want to show user-friendly URL, but my system is very large and has 10 categories (restaurants, cafes, shops, etc ...). Each category has different layout and actions for admin panel.

Please, give me some advice. Thanks.

UPDATES:

Owner can see ONLY his place.
There are models restaurants, shops, etc with field 'owner_id'.

Comment: can you tell us what are different models in your application which gives the clear idea of how to do that.?

Comment: I have only one model - User with different roles

Comment: I need to know how to render from one URL to another with calculations id

Comment: you don't have models for each of the different categories, e.g. shop, cafe, restaurants?

Comment: your description implies that a given user only owns a single business. is this correct?

Comment: i mean to say that is there any model for category then only route can be defined..?

Comment: is any owner allowed to see the category details page of other owners? categories is a bit too generic of a term. might want to use businesses or locations instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, since owner can only see his place, thus only logged in user can visit `http://somesite.com/his_name`.

Secondly, you need to have this in your `routes.rb`

```
get "/:username" => "users#user_place"
```

Then, I just assume you have all the classes used below. In your `users_controller.rb`, here is the code:

```
def user_place
    # suppose you are using Devise, you should be able to use `current_user`
    # authenticate user before this method
    unless current_user
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end

    restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_user_id current_user.id
    if restaurant.present?
        redirect_to restaurant
    end

    # similar code for your other categories
end
```